# Creating Canonical URL for Dynamic Page

Tags: canonical-link, canonicalization

I already created the Canonical URL for Dynamic Page using below code

**My code:**

```
function aioseo_filter_canonical_url( $url ) {
            $pageurl="medical-billing-coding-services/";
            $statecode=mp_usstate_slug_shortcode();
              if ( is_singular() && strpos($url,$pageurl)!==false && !empty($statecode)) {
                 $newurl=substr($url,0,-1);
                 $newurl .= '-' . $statecode . '/';
                 return $newurl;
               }
              return $url;
             }
```

**Output is:**

```
<link rel="canonical" href="https://example.com/medical-billing-coding-services-alabama/" />
```

I need the canonical URL should appear like below, which means state name should appear before

```
https://example.com/alabama-medical-billing-coding-services/
```

I want to use the same code to make the URL change like above. How to change it?

Comment: As far as I see, the URL from the current output and the "I need" snippet is the same. So what's the problem with the given code?

Comment: Code is working fine but I want "alabama" should comes at first and then "medical-billing-coding-services". How can I change it using the code.